# In python how do I get floats to display what I'm trying to display?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, floating-point

In truecount() no matter where I put float() it always returns 1.0 when it should be giving me something around 0.505. I know its probably something to do with how I formatted everything but any help with what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. p.s. I am very new to programming

```
def count():
    global totalCards
    global cardCount
    card = int(raw_input("input card. "))
    totalCards = totalCards - 1
    if card == 1:
        print "card invalid"
    else:
        if card <= 6 and card > 1:
            cardCount = cardCount + 1
        elif card == 10:
            cardCount = cardCount - 1
        elif card >= 7 and card <= 9:
            cardCount = cardCount
    return

def truecount():
    global cardCount
    global truecardCount
    global totalCards
    global decks
    decksRemaining = float(totalCards/52)
    truecardCount = float(cardCount / decksRemaining)
    return

def main():
    run = True
    totalCards = 0
    cardCount = 0
    truecardCount = 0.0
    while run == True:
        print "Welcome to my card counter. Start using when dealer 
shuffles."
        user_input = raw_input("Type R When you're ready to start. Type X if 
you want to quit.")
        if user_input.upper() == "R":
            global truecardCount 
            truecardCount = 0
            global cardCount
            cardCount = 0
            runCount = True
            decks = int(raw_input("What is the amount of decks in the shoe? 
"))
            global totalCards 
            totalCards = decks * 52
            while runCount == True:  
                count()
                truecount()
                print(float(truecardCount))
        elif user_input.upper() == "X":
            run == False
        else:
```

Comment: Applying `float` to the result of a division doesn't make the division a floating-point division if it wasn't already. It just gets you the integer you would have gotten otherwise, but represented as a float.

Comment: Instead of `float(totalCards/52)`, use `totalCards/52.0`.

Comment: In Py3 `division` handling changes, so you can use `__future__`, e.g.: `from __future__ import division` to bring forward Py3 behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: `decksRemaining = float(totalCards/52)` you are dividing by an integer.

If you are using Python 2.7 dividing by an integer by an integer will give you an integer result. E.g. `5/2` will give you `2`.

So, you can do `totalCards/52.0` to get the result you want.

Alternatively, to use Python 3+ division, you can do:
`from __future__ import division`
and then division should work as you expect, i.e. `5/2` will give you `2.5`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an integer division before applying your conversion to float. In Python 2.x, an integer division returns an integer, not a float.

You have several options:

- `decksRemaining = totalCards/52.0`
- `decksRemaining = float(totalCards)/52`
- `from __future__ import division` and `decksRemaining = totalCards/52` (so that you would have the Python 3.x behavior regarding integer divisions)